# Div faded background at toggle

Tags: jquery, css

There have two divs in same page, one of them is hidden and toggle with the other div at click of a button using jQuery.

Is it possible to give the hidden div a "fade in" effect so when the two divs toggle the new div gets a background color that "fade" to transparant in 2-3 seconds to highlight the new div?

Sorry for some incorrect english.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried..

Comment: I have no becuse I dont know what effect to use, thats the question.

Comment: At least, you could have posted the HTML code for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#element").fadeOut(2000);
$("#element2").fadeIn(2000);
```

[.fadeOut() API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
[.fadeIn() API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 0):

What about using jQuery UI's .effect() function to highlight the second div after you fade it in?

First div fades out, then the second fades in and gets highlighted for 3 seconds.

```
$('#div1').fadeOut(500, function () {
    $('#div2').fadeIn(500, function () {
        $('#div2').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
    });
});
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/8mEL4/

```
$(function () {
   $("#element1").fadeOut( { duration: 1000, queue: false });
   $('#element2').effect('highlight',{ duration: 1000, queue: false });
});
```

I have set `queue : false` for simultaneous animate effect and used [jQuery UI/Effects/Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) for highlighting effect.